# Tkinter png image

Tags: tkinter, png, display

I'm doing a little project in Python 3.9.8 and I'm wondering how to display the transparency of a PNG image on tkinter. Here's the code I've got so far:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import pygame.mixer
import signal
import time

def on_exit(signum, frame):
    print("closed by admin")
    time.sleep(5)

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, on_exit)

pygame.mixer.init()


root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-topmost', True)
root.overrideredirect(True)

image = Image.open('OIP.png')
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (screen_width // 2) - (image.width // 2)
y = (screen_height // 2) - (image.height // 2)

root.geometry(f'{image.width}x{image.height}+{x}+{y}')

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=image.width, height=image.height, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)

canvas.create_image(image.width // 2, image.height // 2, image=photo)

canvas.pack()

def close_window(event):
    root.destroy()
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()

root.bind('<Escape>', close_window)

root.mainloop()
```

As I've made a borderless tkinter window, I'd like to be able to display the transparency of png images instead of white.

My problem is that canva displays the transparency of my image as white and not as transparent as it is.

Here is my image file: [image: My image]

Comment: The canvas is not transparent, so the white part is the background color of the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

This is a windows only answer:[tk reference doc](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.htm#M14)
`-transparentcolor`

One trick is to set the background color of the canvas to an arbitrary color, then make that color transparent in the root window.

For example, let's say #fffffe makes the color transparent.

```
root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "#fffffe")
```

And set the background of the canvas to #fffffe.

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=image.width, height=image.height, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, bg='#fffffe')
```

So the full code...

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import pygame.mixer
import signal
import time

def on_exit(signum, frame):
    print("closed by admin")
    time.sleep(5)

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, on_exit)

pygame.mixer.init()


root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-topmost', True)
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "#fffffe")
image = Image.open('OIP.png')
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (screen_width // 2) - (image.width // 2)
y = (screen_height // 2) - (image.height // 2)

root.geometry(f'{image.width}x{image.height}+{x}+{y}')

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=image.width, height=image.height, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, bg='#fffffe')

canvas.create_image(image.width // 2, image.height // 2, image=photo)

canvas.pack()

def close_window(event):
    root.destroy()
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()

root.bind('<Escape>', close_window)

root.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is better to state that `-transparentcolor` is supported by Windows only as stated in [`tk reference doc`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.htm#M14).

Answer (score 0):

If your background is white, then it will be white where the image is transparent. What else would you expect?

It is traditional to show an image with an alpha channel over a fine checkerboard pattern, in order to expose where it's transparent. Here is your image over such a pattern:

[image: dice over checkerboard]

If you look closely, you can see that the dice are also a bit transparent.